# hello world fails to show up in emulator

Tags: android

I followed Hello World tutorial exactly.  Emulator comes up but fails to show Hello World text.  Here's the log info:

```
[2011-11-26 20:06:57 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-11-26 20:06:57 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-26 20:06:57 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-11-26 20:06:57 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AndroidPhone'
[2011-11-26 20:06:57 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AndroidPhone'
[2011-11-26 20:07:09 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-11-26 20:07:09 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-11-26 20:45:37 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-26 20:45:37 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-26 20:45:38 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
```

After about 1/2 hour, this shows up in the log...

```
[2011-11-26 20:48:59 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-11-26 20:48:59 - HelloAndroid] (null)
[2011-11-26 20:49:02 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

I’ve read posts on similar problem.  I’ve tried many suggested solutions including restarting Eclipse, rebooting and restarting eclipse, creating a new project in eclipse, starting emulator first with “wipe user data” box checked, increasing the emulator time-out period from 5000 to 20000, unlocking emulator by clicking and dragging mouse, clicking Menu and Home buttons on emulator, and running the Layout version.  Nothing worked.  I’m using Android 4.0 AVD and Eclipse Build id: 20110916-0149 and the latest JDC on a Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop.

It’s hard to believe Google would make this discouraging example as the first impression new users experience.   Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: I'd advise you to develop on a real device - the emulator is a painful experience!

Answer (score 0):

When you have the "Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!", try to wait some seconds, 
dont close the VM and 
reclick on "Launch Buton"

Comment: I have tried leaving the emulator up and clicking Run from the Run menu in Eclipse again.  It says it is loading it onto existing device 'emulator-5554' but again, nothing ever shows up.  Is that what you mean by the Launch Button?

Comment: @user1067564 Did you unlock the keylock that's in place by default before clicking launch for the second time *(the emulator behaves like a real phone)*? Should be a slider which you have to drag to the side, there should be instructions on the screen if you click into it too. If this is still present, your apps won't get displayed in the foreground.

Comment: Yes, but when you launch the VM, dont close it ! Juste wait some seconds and reclick on launch button (Green Triangle)

Comment: alextsc - I'm afraid I don't understand what keylock you are referring to.  The emulator shows 2 panels.  On the left is a black screen with the word android on it in the middle in fancy glowing letters.  On the right is a keypad and buttons.  I don't see anything that looks like a keylock.  There is no slider or instructions.

Comment: Erowlin - if VM means emulator, then yes, I tried that.  I waited a long time, left the emulator up, then reclicked the green triangle. 
[2011-11-28 19:38:14 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldActivity activity launch
[2011-11-28 19:38:14 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AndroidPhone'
[2011-11-28 19:38:14 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-28 19:38:15 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
But nothing ever shows up in the emulator.

Comment: if android text keeps on glowing there on the on the screen, it means your emulator actually failed to boot up, but still trying in hope of success / or its image actually got corrupt.

I have faced the same problem many times...

It happpens because of low resources available, so edit you emulator and decrease its RAM size, keep in mind the RAM you have in your system and assign accordingly, instead of giving a any high random number.
disable snapsot in emulator settings...
or finaly saving the same emulator with new name helps as it creates a new emulator and delete the corrupted one...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Activity project, it effectively creates a Hello World app. Create a new project. Don't modify it. Just run it. If you don't see a Hello world message, check your install.

Comment: I tried that and the same thing happened.  The emulator comes up but nothing appears on the screen other than the default glowing android letters.  I'll give up now and maybe try again later on a different computer.

Comment: Probably a good idea. You might want to check your path statement as well. Some stuff has moved around over the last few releases. About 2 weeks ago I checked my sales stats and noticed that 98% of my installed apps were at 2.2 and above. I ripped everything out and reinstalled starting at level 2.2. I also made sure that the Java JDE was at 1.5 and not the latest 1.7. Eclipse runs so much smoother now... (BTW: I'm running Window 7 Pro 64bit and installed in Program Files (x86)).

Comment: I tried again on a different computer and got the same result.  Then I deleted the latest AVD (API14) and installed 2.1 instead.  FINALLY that worked!  So evidently there is a problem with the API 14 emulator.